# How to return useful information in JPA custom query whose return value is not 1?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have several custom queries in an interface that extends JpaRepository. The interface is analogous to the below (note: the below is just for illustration, and may have errors, but don't concern yourself with that).

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<SMark, String> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO my_table(id, col_1, col_2) " +
        "values(:col_1, :col_2))", nativeQuery = true)
int insertRecord(@Param("col_1") String col_1, @Param("col_2") String col_2);
```

So, my issue is that I am finding it difficult to do anything useful with the int return type for anything other than a successful query (which will return a 1). Is there a way to do anything useful with the return other than sending the value as part of the response? In other words, if the response is not a 1, and an exception is not thrown, can the non-1 response be translated into something more informative to the user?

For example, I am currently doing the following, which I would like to improve upon if I was a confident about the not-1 status:

```
    if(status == 1) {
        StatusResponse statusResponse = new StatusResponse("Successful Delete ", null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(statusResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        StatusResponse statusResponse = new StatusResponse("Delete not successful (lacking details from response)  ", null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(statusResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
```

Grateful for any response. Thanks!

Comment: By response you mean a REST Api response?

Comment: @Ausgefuchster yes a REST Api response is certainly acceptable.

Comment: In the interface you can create one default method with params and invoke the above method and implement logic there.

Comment: @SagarRout, I appreciate response, but do not understand what you are suggesting (.e.g "..and invoke the above method and implement logic there").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend the approach of using return type as valid operation or not. I would prefer having database level constraint like unique constraint, check constraint or trigger check for insert/update/delete.

Nevertheless, we can use default method inside interface and throw database exception and in Spring you can configure ExceptionHandler to wrap the exception and return with some valid error code ?

```
    public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<SMark, String> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO my_table(id, col_1, col_2) " +
            "values(:col_1, :col_2))", nativeQuery = true)
    int insertRecord(@Param("col_1") String col_1, @Param("col_2") String col_2);

    default void insert(String col1, String col2) {
        if (insertRecord(col1, col2) != 1) {
            throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("Unable to perform DML operation.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It worked for me. I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the return value of this methods indicates the number of modified objects (in your can it can only be 0 or 1) I would just use it to translate it into a more understandable response.

The simplest case is a REST Api:

When the Method returns 1 the POST/PUT/PATCH call was successful (if there was no other error) and you would return `201 Created` and maybe a little more like a Location header.

And when it returns 0 it means no object got modified and because it's an insert this shouldn't happen and therefore you would return `500 InternalServerError`

But I would say in your case this is redundant because as I said it's an insert , you only have those two return options and I guess if something doesn't work during the insert you already get an exception by spring boot and therefore when you called the method without getting an error I would say it was successful.

But ofcourse you can double check to be sure and maybe even use it for tests to enforce the expected behavior or something else.

Comment: thanks for great response. Question:  are you using REST API, and 201 for 1 versus 500 for 0, as an analogy, or are you saying I could say 201 Created in return for 1 and 500 Internal Server error for 0? I don't think you are saying the latter. Guess I am still a bit confused. Please see my updated to post where I added what I am currently doing. Thanks again.

Comment: Alright so here is what I would do with this number: 
If it's a query where exactly one entity should change; ignore it, because As I said it should've worked and therefore you don't really get any additional information.
If it's a query which changes multiple or zero entities you can return it to say 'x entities affected'. 
So for your case e.g. the delete you added I would only use it if the query doesn't delete exactly one enity. Otherwise `204 No Content`  for successful and 4xx / 5xx depending on the error (4xx is for some kind of invalid request, 5xx something internal/your server)